# Meaning of 銀星4型 in this sentence

Tags: meaning

The sentence is from dragon ball, the speaker is driving his car, chasing some other guys. He just said "これじゃとてもおいつかん!"

> たしかやつらのより新型の銀星{ぎんせい}4型のカプセルがあっただろ!

I didn't find info on 銀星 in the dictionary. My guess is the sentence means something like :

> They probably had a newer model of "type 4 stars capsule" (than mine)!

I'm also confused about the の after やつら, I would expect a (に)は instead...

**Edit :** Ok, on second thought, I think I misunderstood the particle より for the adverb より.

I now think the sentence means something like :

> I was sure I had a "type 4 stars" capsule newer than theirs.

Comment: Dragon Ball Wiki seems to translate it as "[Silverstar 4](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Yamcha#Weapons_and_vehicles)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would satisfy you. After having googled, since I don't have any idea either, the word **銀星4型** is very likely to be borrowing the name of a vehicle which a character called **[Yamcha](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Yamcha)** is riding at in an anime **[Dragonball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball)**.

Here is a [**dictionary**](http://kaz.topaz.ne.jp/well/dragonball/terms.html) of the terms of Dragonball....

Excerpt

> 銀星４型【ぎんせいよんがた／02(015)-061(01)】
>
> ヤムチャがカプセルにして携帯していた新型の乗り物の型番。

Translated

> Type Ginsei 4 ( I don't know how in the English version the word is translated, so this is my translation. )
>
> 【ぎんせいよんがた／02(015)-061(01)】
>
> A new type **[Capsule](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Capsule)** ( in English ) portable vehicle which Yamcha has.

I think the **[image would be like this](http://dragonballon.com/?p=164)** ( though the **type of the vehicle number ( name )** is different. So from the **dictionary** of the Dragonball terms above, **once you "throw" the portable capsule into the air**, the vehicle ( 銀星4型 ) shows up.

Wish you have good fun.